# Predictive probability inference

Tags: probability-theory, machine-learning, bayesian

I'm quite new to probability theory, yet I'm reading on deep learning and trying to understand some basic concepts.

They write down Bayes rule in the following form:

$$ p(\theta|D) = \frac{p(\theta)p(D|\theta)}{p(D)} = \frac{p(\theta)p(D|\theta)}{\int_{\theta \in \Theta}p(D|\theta)p(\theta)d\theta}$$

where:

- $\theta$ - parameters of the model
- *D* - input data
- $p(\theta)$ -  prior probability
- $p(D|\theta)$ - likelihood
- $p(\theta|D)$ - posterior probability
- $p(D) = \int_{\theta \in \Theta}p(D|\theta)p(\theta)d\theta$ - evidence

Now, they introduce what they call **predictive probability** which is denoted as $p(y|D)$ or $p(y|D,x)$ where y is the right answer for the next question x. Then they write:
$$p(y|D) = \int_{\Theta}p(y|\theta)p(\theta|D)d\theta \propto \int_{\Theta}p(y|\theta)p(\theta)p(D|\theta)d\theta$$

At this point, I'm lost. Please could anybody explain in detail this marginalization?

Comment: Can you see that $p(\theta|D) \propto p(\theta)p(D|\theta)$?

Comment: @N74 I understand this transformation, but can't get the marginalization thing, or rather how they went from p(y|D) to the integration.

Answer (score 2):

By marginalising the joint distribution you have
$$
\begin{align}
p(y|D) &= \int_{\Theta} p(y, \theta | D)\operatorname{d}\theta \\
&= \int_{\Theta} p(y|\theta, D)p(\theta |D)\operatorname{d}\theta,
\end{align}
$$
and since you seem happy with the claim that $p(\theta|D) \propto p(\theta)p(D|\theta)$, then it remains to claim that
$$
p(y|\theta, D)=p(y|\theta),
$$
which is an assumption, but it is one that is normally assumed true in the context of parameterised statistical models where the parameters, $\theta$, completely specify the conditional distribution. In the particular problem you are considering it amounts to the assumption that; "the distribution of the random variable $Y$ at the input point $x$ is completely specified by a parameter $\theta$" - that is all that you once you know a point $x$ and a parameter $\theta$ you know all you need to know about the distribution of $Y$, or in terms of the density functions that for any random variable $Z$ you have that $p(Y|x, \theta, Z) = p(Y|x, \theta)$.

Comment: How do you get $p(\theta,D)p(\theta|D)$ from $p(\theta|D)$ when go from the first integration to the second?

Comment: I don't follow your question? My first integrand to the second is simply $p(y, \theta  | D) = p(y |\theta, D)p(\theta | D)$ which with less visual clutter is $q(y, \theta) = q(y |\theta)q(\theta)$ - where $q(\cdot) = p(\cdot  | D)$

Comment: Sorry for my silliness, but: $p(y,\theta|D) = p(y|(\theta|D))p(\theta|D)$, then how do we get $p(y|\theta, D)$?

Comment: Where are you seeing notation like $p(A|(B|C))$ and how do you interpret? You have a distribution which has been conditioned on $D$ and we write $p(A, B, \ldots | D)$ to denote the density - but we may as well write $q(A, B \ldots ) := p(A, B, \ldots | D)$. Then the conditioned density $q$ is a valid probability so the usual decomposition $q(A, B) = q(A | B)q(B)$ holds, but $q$ is just $p$ with some extra conditioning so we have $q(A|B) = p(A | B, D)$ and $q(B) = p(B|D)$.